# interchanging sum and lim with uniformly convergence series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n$ be a uniformly convergence function series with $f_n$ continuous for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Let $a$ be a point in the domain of all $f_n$. Prove that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \lim_{x\rightarrow a} f_n(x)$$

I have attempted to let $c=\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f_n(x)$ and to prove $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|f_n(x)-c|=0$, but still have no idea. I also suspect this has some connection to the monotone convergence theorem. Thanks for any help!

Comment: What do you know about the domain of the $f_n$? Is that a real interval, an abstract space...?

Comment: @EM90 a real interval.

Comment: What you want to proof is not correct. You need the uniform convergence of the function series

Comment: @Fred sorry I forgot to add this condition. I've edited the problem.